# INSERT IGNORE in MS SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there mysql's INSERT IGNORE equivalent  in MS SQL Server 2005 or something similar?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the mysql INSERT IGNORE feature, but the documentation I am reading makes it sound like all it does is ignore(silently fail) attempts to insert a record with a primary key that already exists in the table.

If that is what you are looking for, SQL Server has a similar functionality, but you have to apply it to the primary key or unique constraint when you create it.

Read about [the IGNORE_DUP_KEY option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) of a unique index.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work as I thought it will. It doesn't issue an error but it gives a warning which is also not a solution form me.

Answer (score 2):

you can implement something like this with an [INSTEAD OF](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6113179.html) [trigger](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1804), intercepting the default insert action to perform updates where existing rows are detected. Not quite as out-of-the-box as the MySql variation, but more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have two viable options:

One is to filter out the wrong values before you try. Maybe add a where clause like:

```
WHERE newValues NOT IN (SELECT pk_col FROM yourTable)
```

OR you can use try-catch because whenever you work with errors, normally something with try-catch is your best friend. Try this out:

```
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO yourTable(pk_col,other_date)
    SELECT 'PK Value That Already Exists','saflaksdfj'
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    --You can choose to do anything in response to an error like nothing!
END CATCH
```

Comment: I'm not sure this address the issue. IGNORE will swallow the error and continue. This is very useful if you're dealing with million of records... with TRY..CATCH seems like swallow the error and finish, but the purpose is to swallow and continue!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what your application is - maybe the `REPLACE` could help?!

Comment: No such functionality in MS SQL Server apart from text replace. There is a MERGE but SQL2008 only.