# How to implement cross-DBMS insert-ignore with Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

By the nature of my data primary key (which is composite) uniqueness violation is a frequent thing to meet. In every such a case the violating record (the new one) is to be discarded silently (leaving the old record with the same key intact) and let the others to be inserted.

MySQL, for example, lets us do this easily by using `INSERT IGNORE` instead of bare `INSERT`. But my application has to be cross-database.

What can be the best way to implement this behaviour?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760508/insert-ignore-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: If you need any special logic you may want to map Create operation to a stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged your question with `entity-framework`, I'll suggest you try generating as many Models, as you have different databases. Then using LINQ to perform `INSERT IGNORE` will be a breeze.

NOTE: LINQ-to-SQL doesn't support bulk insert, so you might want to use parameterized SQL with each Model.